# How to send emails that loop through arrays from firestore database

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, sendgrid

I'm trying to send a user receipt from an eCommerce store. How do I loop through the data to send

I have tried using [] on the dynamic data.

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
admin.initializeApp();
const db = admin.firestore();

// Sendgrid Config
import * as sgMail from "@sendgrid/mail";

const API_KEY = functions.config().sendgrid.key;
const TEMPLATE_ID = functions.config().sendgrid.template;
sgMail.setApiKey(API_KEY);

//FUNCTIONS

export const newOrder = functions.firestore
.document("checkout/{checkoutId}/products/{productId}")
.onCreate(async (change, context) => {
// Read booking document
const postSnap = await db
  .collection("checkout/{checkoutId}/products")
  .doc(context.params.productId)
  .get();

const booking = postSnap.data() || {};

//Email
const msg = {
  to: "wilmutsami@gmail.com",
  from: "test@example.com",
  templateId: TEMPLATE_ID,
  dynamic_template_data: {
    subject: "Hey there, thank you for your order!",
    name: booking.name,
    amount: booking.amount
    }
  };

 //Send it
 return sgMail.send(msg);
});
```

Expected results are an email to the user displays a table of items that you ordered

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the data of the document that triggered the Cloud Function at `checkout/{checkoutId}/products/{productId}` you don't need to do

```
await db
  .collection("checkout/{checkoutId}/products")
  .doc(context.params.productId)
  .get();
```

As explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events):

> When a function is triggered, **it provides a snapshot of the data
>   related to the event**. You can use this snapshot to read from or write
>   to the document that triggered the event, or use the Firebase Admin
>   SDK to access other parts of your database.

You can easily get the values of the document fields through the `snap` [`DocumentSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot) as follows:

```
export const newOrder = functions.firestore
.document("checkout/{checkoutId}/products/{productId}")
.onCreate(async (snap, context) => {

      const docData = snap.data();
      const name = docData.name;
      const amount = docData.amount;

      // You can then use those values in the rest of your code

    const msg = {
      to: "wilmutsami@gmail.com",
      from: "test@example.com",
      templateId: TEMPLATE_ID,
      dynamic_template_data: {
        subject: "Hey there, thank you for your order!",
        name: name,
        amount: amount
        }
      };

    return sgMail.send(msg);

});
```

Comment: Okay, but how do I send arrays from the database to the email?

Comment: If you look at the Sengrid documentation https://sendgrid.com/docs/ui/sending-email/how-to-send-an-email-with-dynamic-transactional-templates/#design-a-dynamic-transactional-template you will see that you have to include an array in the dynamic_template_data object.

Comment: I have tried following it but still haven't crack it. Could you kindly show me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Could you kindly point out what i've done wrong, I've tried following the documentation

Comment: On which part you are having problem? In your question you don't explain on which data you want to 'loop through the data to send'. A field of type array in your document?